# Facebook API call inside FB Application requires login (just in IE)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, graph

i made a FB application that shows the upcoming events of a public page. i use the following javascript:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
...
FB.init({
    appId  : {APP_ID},
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

FB.api('/{page_id}/events?since=today', function(response) {
    ...
});
```

the code runs fine in chrome and firefox (although just when uploaded to a server and executed inside FB (https://apps.facebook.com/{app_name}/), not local or when called direct from the hosting server) but when run in IE i get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}
```

i dont see why the user has to login, since the app anyways already runs inside FB. any ideas?

thanks 
simon

Answer (score 0):

As facebook app runs in iframe you should set up p3p policy in order to let ie runs,
put this code in to your Global.asax (assuming you are on asp.net):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");

}
```